# How to write and read file to temporary folder in windows

Tags: java, graphviz

I am using graphviz to parse a code to tree image. You know, Graphviz is read a file and then write to file image. So, how to write that file into temporary folder in windows and then read that file again. This is my code :

```
     DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
     StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(tree);

     String OS = System.getProperty("os.name");
     Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();


            try {

                File file = new File("D:\\workspace\\output.dot"); // create a file
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile()));
                bw.write(st2);
                bw.close();


                String dotPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Graphviz2.38\\bin\\dot.exe";
                String fileInputPath = "D:\\workspace\\output.dot";
                String fileOutputPath = "D:\\workspace\\treeImage.png";
                String tParam = "-Tpng";
                String tOParam = "-o";

                String[] cmd = new String[5];
                cmd[0] = dotPath;
                cmd[1] = tParam;
                cmd[2] = fileInputPath;
                cmd[3] = tOParam;
                cmd[4] = fileOutputPath;

                rt.exec(cmd);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Failed to write to file");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [File.createTempFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
,this will correctly handle all temp directories of all OS that have a JVM.

Answer (score 0):

You can get os temp directory path like this:

```
    String tempPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    File tempFile = new File(tempPath + File.separator + "myTempFile.dat");
    // todo read/write file
```